# scanf return value not as expected

Tags: c, return-value, scanf

`Scanf` should return the number of characters taken as inputted..**but strangely returning only 1 all the time.**

```
scanf ("%d",&num_test_cases);   

for (i=0;i<num_test_cases;i++)
{
    level=scanf ("%s",ch);
    printf ("\n %s\n",ch);
    printf ("%lld\n",level);

}
```

Sample Input :

```
4
lrl
rll
r
lllr
```

Output :

```
lrl
1
rll
1
r
1
lllr
1
```

Comment: I am guessing you are expecting scanf to return the number of characters entered and that is not how scanf works. You asked scanf to scan one item (%s) and it returned that it succesfully scanned in one item.

Comment: Returning 1 is good.  It means something was stored in `ch`.  `0` means nothing was read (unlikely here).  `EOF` means `stdin` isat end-of-file (closed).

Comment: C11dr §7.21.6.2 16 "The fscanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, `scanf()` returns number of items successfully read...
Actually,`printf()` returns the number of characters successfully written on the output!

So,as your scanf is accepting only 1 input for each iteration,hence,`level` variable in your program is returning 1 as a result in each iteration!